# Bat file that opens links in firefox on time interval

Tags: windows, batch-file, firefox

I am rather new in this programming so very still learning. Here is my question:

I have some webpages

```
www.page1.com
www.page2.com
www.page3.com
```

and so on and so on.

Now I want to be very specific in what I want the bat file to do. It is Windows 10.

Open firefox browser
open www.page1.com
wait for xx seconds 
then open www.page2.com in same firefox browser but in new tab
wait for xx seconds 
then open www.page3.com in same firefox browser but in new tab

and so on

So when finished it will be a firefox browser with all my pages open in tabs - if there is 10 pages there will be 10 tabs.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show your efforts, of what you tried

Comment: Sorry i dont think I have tried so much yet - but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: What did you try so much? Post the batch script which you tried